# Is /root a hard requirement for a modern Linux system? What about POSIX? UNIX?

Tags: root, posix, standard

I moved `/root` to `/home/root` and changed the appropriate entry in `/etc/passwd` in my Linux system quite some time ago and everything's worked until recently when I discovered that at least the firejail application hardcodes the root home directory and stops working otherwise under [some](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/5336) circumstances. I presume it will be patched eventually but still.

I wonder if the root user home directory in Linux must be in `/root`, or it's still movable just like home directories of other users.

Is there anything in POSIX which standardizes this? What about other Unixes?

Comment: I cannot tell regarding standardization matters. What I can tell is that, whatever the *nix-like I (as many I presume) have root and home in separate partitions. Having root user home in /root is just helpful whenever I need the home partition **not** to be mounted.

Comment: Mac OS X (before the ugly macOS name change) used `/var/root`. maybe it still does? way olden systems probably have `/` for the directory

Comment: @thrig `~root` is still `/var/root` on macOS, which is actually `/private/var/root`, which is part of the `/System/Volumes/Data` mount point (so it's _also_ `/System/Volumes/Data/private/var/root`). It all makes sense to somebody.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

POSIX doesn’t have much to say about the administrative user; when privileges are discussed, they are discussed in terms of process privileges (since that’s what really matters in POSIX-style systems). It acknowledges [the existence of the root user](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpwuid.html#tag_16_214_06_01) but doesn’t define any requirements on its home directory.

The FHS [explicitly marks `/root` as optional](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s14.html), saying

> The root account's home directory may be determined by developer or local preference, but this is the recommended default location.

It’s worth considering that root’s home is somewhat special, in that it makes life easier if it is accessible and on a volume with some available space when root needs to log in, or if it doesn’t block unmount operations on anything other than the root volume; this is why it is traditionally on the root volume, and not on user home directory volume(s) when the latter are separate from `/`. But that’s just a practical consideration, not a requirement in any widely-acknowledged standard I’m aware of.

The flip side of the coin is that many operating environments no longer have a root home directory *at all* (and not just in containers).

Answer (score -5):

Some years ago Unix was a multi-user system. Nowadays some Wayland guys cannot remember anymore. But in the last century a typical Unix installation mounted `/home` from a NFS server. In this case it is no option to put the HOME directory of the root user in the directory `/home`, because root would not be able to fix any NFS problems, because he will not be able to login, because the HOME directory would not be available. This means the HOME directory of the root user needs to be on the root volume. This is not a standard but useful.

Comment: The Wayland implementations I’ve used still work fine on multi-user systems, with multiple users logged in simultaneously.

Comment: What relevance does Wayland have to the question?